# Using Python. How to save a 4 dimension array (21,32,1024,1024) as a tif image. biomedicine

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, save

I want to save an stack of arrays in a tiff file, so a microscopy software can read it in channels and z planes, as images. So this is a 4 dimensions array: (21,32,1024,1024). But I do not find a way.

For example using: `io.imsave(os.path.join(outpath), stack2)`, this is saved as a stack of individual images but not in grups of 32 channels representing the 21 z planes.

do you know any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the TIFF specification does not handle multi-channel Z stacks, additional metadata needs to be saved with the image data. There are two common metadata formats for saving ZCYX images in TIFF for bio-imaging: [OME-TIFF](https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/ome-model/6.2.0/#ome-tiff) and [ImageJ hyperstacks](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-8.html). OME-TIFF is supported by more software. [Tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) can read and write both formats:

```
import numpy
from tifffile import imwrite

image = numpy.zeros((21, 32, 1024, 1024), dtype='uint16')

# write OME-TIFF
imwrite('zcyx.ome.tif', image)

# write ImageJ hyperstack
imwrite('zcyx.tif', image, imagej=True)
```

Comment: hello, so, the normal imwrite, save as all the images consecutive. And the image J says. ValueError: ImageJ does not support data type 'l'

Comment: Note the `ome.tif` file ending, which instructs tifffile to use OME-TIFF format. ImageJ hyperstack only supports certain datatypes: uint8, uint16, or float32.

Comment: Hello, so the ome.tif did not work, but i changed to 16 bits format and the imagej worked perfectly. Thank you very much! I couldn't find that parameter. I love you

Comment: it saved anyway as consecutive images

Comment: Either your version of tifffile is out of date or the software you are using to load the file does not properly support/detect OME-TIFF.

Comment: maybe, I was using fiji. I will try with zen when I have it in some time. Thank you!

Comment: Fiji does support OME-TIFF via Bio-Formats: File -> Import -> Bio-Formats. ZEN does support OME-TIFF, but not ImageJ hyperstacks.